# Deploy Rails App with nginx and unicorn - not opening application home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, unicorn

I'm new to deploy Rails application using **Nginx** and **unicorn**.

I'v deployed the app and installed the unicorn and **Nginx** but it is accessing files and folders from public folder instead of running my **Rails application.**

I have added **config/unicorn.rb** with:

```
app_dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/..')

worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 3000

listen app_dir + '/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock', backlog: 64

working_directory app_dir

pid app_dir + '/shared/pids/unicorn.pid'

stderr_path app_dir + '/shared/log/unicorn.log'
stdout_path app_dir + '/shared/log/unicorn.log'

 stderr_path "#{app_dir}/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
 stdout_path "#{app_dir}/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"


preload_app true

GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) &&
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true


before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I have configure `/etc/init.d/unicorn_instant_booking`

```
set -e

USAGE="Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|rotate|force-stop>"

USER="root"
APP_NAME="instant_booking"
APP_ROOT="/$USER/rails/$APP_NAME"
ENV="production"

PATH="/$USER/.rbenv/shims:/home/$USER/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E $ENV -D"
PID="$APP_ROOT/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
OLD_PID="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PID && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PID`
}

case $1 in
  start)
    sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
    echo "Starting $APP_NAME"
    su - $USER -c "$CMD"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig QUIT && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  force-stop)
    echo "Force stopping $APP_NAME"
    sig TERM && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
  restart|reload|upgrade)
    sig USR2 && echo "reloaded $APP_NAME" && exit 0
```

and  **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
    upstream app {
    server unix:/root/rails/instant_booking/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
        root /root/rails/instant_booking/public;

        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name mydomainapp.com;

        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404 @app;

        location @app {
        proxy_pass http://mydomainapp.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

I'm not getting what I'm missing. Please help
Thanks.

Comment: change `@rails` with `@app` since your upstream is named app. I don't get why do you have a `location /` block. How did you get this nginx vhost?

Comment: No I do not have Nginx vhost. I have seen somewhere and suggested me to do that

Comment: Because that server block is not good at all. Here you can find a good one to test with: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: and it's a bad practice to mount the app under root.

Comment: Now please check my configuration I'v edited here, this is again accessing my public folder from rails app but not running rails application like as it runs on rails server

Comment: proxy_pass http://app;

Comment: It shows me invalid url in nginx configuration for app
nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:45

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141655/discussion-between-jai-kumar-rajput-and-radubogdan).